# Splitting a string in arduino for scrolling LCD screen

Tags: c, string, split, arduino

Hi I'm trying to figure out how to split the following LCD display code for a scrolling LED effect. but when I try to use the Substring function I get the error "class string has no member named Substring"

```
void setup()
{
    lcd.init(); 
    }
void loop()
{
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) { 
  lcd.clear ();
lcd.backlight();
    lcd.setCursor(i, 1);
    String printy = "Hello World         ";
    String printy1 = printy.SubSting(0, 20-i);
    String printy2 = printy.SubSting(20-i, 20);
    lcd.print(printy1);
delay(500);
}
}
```

Comment: "SubSting"? Have you tried "substring"?

Comment: yeah, from what I understand Arduino is basically a slightly dumbed down version of C and I can use substring in c I've tried substring Substring and SubString I'm not sure why it doesn't accept that but I imagine there has to be someway to do this.

Comment: Oh lord, I must be tired, I didn't realize I had sting instead of string. I even misread what you wrote

Comment: That is why it is sometimes necessary to have someone else look at one's code.

Answer (score 1):

It helps if I spelled string correctly and put "substring" instead of "substing", sorry.